# WhatsApp can't be installed

Tags: applications, installation

I seem to be encountering problems installing WhatsApp on my Huawei Y511-U10 model.
I factory resetted my phone yesterday, and downloaded apps a fresh. But whatsapp seems to be the only app that won't get installed successfully. When I try to install it it keeps on showing me "Whatsapp Messenger can't be installed. (Error code -24).
 I contacted Google Play Store and Whatsapp support for help but haven't yet gotten any solution for my problem. If there is some genious mind out there kindly assist me and I'll be greatful

Comment: What android  version your device is running?

Answer (score 1):

Reading all the questions associated with this type error, you get the impression it will require root to enable you to delete the app from the /system partition if it remains.

Previous to doing that, I would suggest trying this, just to be sure it is not a file or folder remnant getting in the way:

> Some apps leave remainders during uninstalls that aid in the
>   restoration of state or level information upon re-installing a later
>   version. Usually these remains are unimportant to a user who does not
>   intend to re-install or to any other user where consistent state or
>   level data is unimportant. These remains have a particular name in an
>   app that can clean them up: "corpse files".
>
> [SDMaid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm)
>   is a disk cleaner that can locate, and delete, files related to
>   corpses. Install the app, and select CorpseFinder from the menu to
>   locate, and, optionally delete them.

DISCLAIMER: I am not the developer, just a satisfied user.

If this is not the solution, see the answers for more intensive actions through other questions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=error+24+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1).